# How can i add iOS 17.1 simulator to Xcode?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, ios17

I have a problem with one of my applications popup view not appearing in iOS 17.1, i need to debug it but i can't find iOS 17.1 to install in Xcode devices and there is no new update for Xcode!

Is this normal?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wg9LQ.png) No iOS 17.1 to select.

Comment: Are you using Xcode 15.1?

Comment: Hi @HangarRash isn't xCode 15.1 still in beta?

Comment: @Lmoro Yes, it is at the moment. But Xcode 15.0 doesn't support iOS 17.1.